Iterating Over a Swift OrderedDictionary Initialized from a JSON
This is a followup question to this StackOverflow post I made, but now I'm trying to iterate over the menu field in the JSON to display all the menu options and allergens in SwiftUI.
I have this ForEach loop that should iterate through all of the keys, but, as an example using the posted JSON snippet, it only displays "Southwest Tofu" and its allergens instead of all of them.
struct TodaysMenuOptionsView: View {
    @Binding var menuItems: OrderedDictionary<String, [String]>
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .leading) {
            ForEach(menuItems.keys.sorted(), id: \.self) { key in
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                    .fill(Color("Menu Options Color"))
                    .frame(height: 100)
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(key)
                            .font(.title3)
                            .fontWeight(.semibold)
                        if let value = menuItems[key] {
                            HStack {
                                ForEach(value, id: \.self) { item in
                                    Text(item)
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    .padding()
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

Here's a snippet of the JSON I'm working with:
   {
    "day": "Friday",
    "locationName": "Memorial Union Quad",
    "coordinate": [38.54141, -121.74845],
    "menu": [
        "Soy Ciltrano Lime Chicken",
        ["",""],
        "Southwest Tofu",
        ["","V"]
    ]
  }

Here's how the data modeling looks like in Swift:
import Foundation
import OrderedCollections

struct Menu : Codable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID { UUID() }
    let day: String
    let locationName: String
    let coordinate: [Double]
    let menu: OrderedDictionary<String, [String]>
    
    func getTodaysLocation(_ today: String)-> String{
        if today == day{
            return locationName
        }
        return ""
    }
    
    
}


Are you familiair with Quicktype? You can paste your json, and it will generate the corresponding code for you. https://app.quicktype.io/

Note, there is no need for @Binding,
you are not changing anything.
Also you should be using let id = UUID() in your Menu.
Use enum CodingKeys ... if you want. And as burni answer's says, use VStack or such.

If you wanted to have the menu key and values inside the RoundedRectangle,
then just simply move the ZStack(alignment: .leading) { inside the
ForEach(menuItems.keys.sorted(), id: \.self). Works well for me.

You are using the wrong Stack. With a ZStack all elements are placed on top of eachother use a VStack instead.
Or better use a List.
